# VueJS-3 How to access raw text of a v-model expression

Tags: vuejs3

For example if my HTML tag says `<input v-model=“foo.bar”>` I need the actual text `foo.bar`, rather than the object that foo.bar resolves to.

In Vue 2 my component was able to use `this.$vnode.data.model.expression`

What is the equivalent in Vue 3?

Comment: `binding.expression` [was removed](https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/3107) in Vue 3 from custom directives and most likely also from the build-in ones. You should start thinking about alternative solution. Why do you need that ?

Comment: My Open Source project, Metawidget, dynamically generates sub-components based on a top-level binding. So I need the original binding text (e.g. `person`) so I can generate sub-components with sub-bindings (e.g. `person.firstname`, `person.surname`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not documented, and kind of a hack, but I just solved it like this:

For `v-model="foo.bar"`

In vue2: `node.$vnode.data.model.expression`

In vue3: `node.$attrs['onUpdate:modelValue'].toString()` returns `$event => ((_ctx.foo.bar) = $event)`, so you can get your `foo.bar` from there.